# CUSP kernel codes

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix, cusp-library

I was wondering if I could find the kernel codes for the spmv and conversions in CUSP library. I scanned the whole library but couldn't find it. Is that proprietary or something like that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't look to hard - the kernel source for every variant of spMV is in every CUSP version ever release (think about it, it is a header based template library...). You can see the device code for the different versions of spMV [here](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/tree/develop/cusp/system/cuda/detail/multiply).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. I was searching for it in the INL files. Silly me